# How to remove or delete comments in excel worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

As I click on the particular cells in excel, comments appears that disturb me much so I want vba code to delete all the comments instantly in the active worksheet.

Comment: Like this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-clearcomments-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 6):

All you really need to do is get a range, then clear comments:

```
Worksheets("MySheet").Activate 
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ClearComments
```

Does that help?

**More Detail**
To get the above code to work, there are several approaches. The one I recommend here is:

- Open your Excel workbook.
- Click the Visual Basic option on the Developer tab. This opens a VBA window with a tree control to the left, which shows the worksheets and workbooks.
- Right-click the worksheet and select Insert Module.
- In the module window that opens, paste the code I show at the bottom of these instructions.
- Save the worksheet as type Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook.
- Close the VBA window.

When back in Excel, hit  to bring up the Run Macro window. You should see your RemoveComments macro listed. Now click Run and your comments should be removed.

I actually tested this, so it will work if done properly. If it still doesn't work for you, be sure that the worksheet in question is the first worksheet in your workbook. If it isn't, then change Worksheets(1).Activate in your RemoveComments Sub so that it refers to the correct worksheet.

```
Sub RemoveComments() 
  Worksheets(1).Activate 
  ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ClearComments 
End Sub
```

Comment: I have made this code like this but it's not working so please help me.   Sub RemoveComments()
Worksheets("24Q INPUT DATA").Activate
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ClearComments
End Sub

Comment: Please see my enhanced reply, above.

Comment: Sir, May I send you excel sheet in which it is not being deleted or removed?......Please will give me your mail id.........So that I can send you that file.

Comment: I've given you plenty of help. This is not a private-tutor forum. If my example doesn't work for you, do the due diligence to figure out why and then report here specifically why it's not working. We are happy to help you once you demonstrate that you're vested in your own success. At this point I must ask you to Invest some actual effort rather than looking for someone to do your work for free. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Please  see my reply

```
Sub delete_comments()
Dim i As Range
     For Each i In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
         i.ClearNotes
     Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It will just add overhead while accessing all the ranges individually in Used range. The other Answer on this post completes this task with directly accessing the used range itself.